# Detect Steam game launch

Tags: steam

I have a script (.ahk) that I want to run when I launch a game from Steam, but me and many others I know that want this use the Steam UI to launch the game, so making a desktop shortcut is out of the running, and I don't want a script that runs in the background constantly. Is there a way to detect Steam launching a game or tell Steam to start additional programs?

Comment: A batch file that launches your game and the auto hotkey script would be the obvious solution, but since you don't want that, you are out of luck.

Comment: [so] or [su] maybe?

Comment: 1) @aytimothy is right, this isn't the right place to ask. 2) using AHK in VAC-enabled games can get you vac banned [no citation, strangers over internet].

Comment: @ardaozkal No, the question is on-topic, the only problem here is that he is already refusing the only possible answer.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Do we support coding help here? I really didn't knew about that. I feel like there should be a SE for beginner developers/small languages.

Comment: @ardaozkal I have delivered answers that contain batch scripts before. Simple automation of **gaming related** tasks is OK I think. But straight up coding help goes on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness this is a script and the example can be used with all kind of stuff, not just games, so this question would be better if he asked it over there. [He might be having the same problem with me tho, toxic community that downvotes and closes everything.](http://puu.sh/jCm65/b552bf3154.png)

Comment: @ardaozkal there's over seven million questions on Stack Overflow that aren't closed or negatively scored. That's a pretty big chunk of "everything" that's been missed.

Comment: @ardaozkal I don't like hacking games, but I do like fixing problems with them. In fact the ahk script has no hotkeys in it whatsoever. It just happens to be the language I'm using for this project.

Comment: @CalebSalyards can you explain me how you do that? I honestly really wonder.

Comment: @ardaozkal What, not have hotkeys in my script? There's just a lot more stuff AHK has that aren't hotkeys, and you can have code that runs on launch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though I'm not sure if this question should be asked in Arqade:

```
XButton2::
IfWinActive, Spotify
{
    MsgBox, The window here is spotify, add your code here, change game up
    return
}
IfWinActive, Idle Master
{
    MsgBox, The window here is idle master, add your code here, change game up
    return
}
IfWinActive, Counter-Strike: Global Offensive
{
    MsgBox, The window here is csgo, add your code here, change game up
    return
}
return
```

Also be aware that AHK is kind of in a VAC gray-zone, see [here](http://woto.com/isahkbannable) for an article I just wrote.

Comment: It is not a duplicate if it is not on Arqade. Second of all, the first 2 things should not be in an answer, but a comment. The rest of your answer misses the question in total. So I gave you a -1.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness fixed

Comment: Ooh.. This is nice - But a bit of a clusterf*** if you have lots of programs in need of hot-keying.

Comment: @aytimothy is the meaning of great person.

Comment: @ardaozkal Welcome to the 1000 club. Also, please **don't ask for upvotes**.

Comment: @aytimothy I asked you to upvote only if you liked it. I usually don't, unless I'm *this* close to a milestone.

Comment: Yea, I'm not worried about that, although I'll look into this as it's very intriguing. The script is to merely allow resizing of the window in a way that I can't set it to do automatically.

Comment: @CalebSalyards a loop and this = what you want.

Comment: @ardaozkal As I said in the question: "I don't want a script that runs in the background constantly" I know I could to this, but I want to keep away from looping scripts. My PC trends to get hung up on these occasionally so the script just stops working outright.

Comment: @CalebSalyards uhmmm try Borderless Gaming. Free on Github, paid for donation on steam.

Comment: Hmm. Borderless Gaming doesn't seem to have what I want, plus I'd have to buy it, but thanks I will definitely remember that program.

Comment: @CalebSalyards it is free [on his github](https://github.com/Codeusa/Borderless-Gaming/releases/download/8.2/BorderlessGaming_8.2__setup.exe), it is paid on steam to support him. It has 0 difference between github and steam version, except 1 achievement.